# How to stop Neo4j running in Docker?

Tags: neo4j

I start `Neo4j` with `docker run neo4j` and when I run `cypher-shell "show database neo4j"` in the container, the status is `online`.
However, running

```
neo4j status
```

gives `Neo4j is not running`.

I am a little confused by this. How can I stop the `Neo4j` in the container? `neo4j stop` obviously does not work.

Comment: Did you mean to say "stop" instead of "neo4j status"?

Answer (score 0):

On cypher-shell, you would need to give `stop database <database-name>`

Answer (score -1):

For make dump database I was using this.
First of all you have to stop neo4j container.

```
docker run --interactive --tty --rm \
   --volume=<dir_where_data_is_stored>/data:/data \  
   --volume=<dir_where_backups_will_stored>/backups:/backups \  
   neo4j:3.5 \
neo4j-admin dump --to=/backups/<dump_name>.dump
```

I had error

> command failed: unable to dump database: AccessDeniedException: /backups

So I simply changed

```
--to=/backups/database.dump
```

to

```
--to=/data/database.dump
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/maintenance/